# Confige place holder in properties file with Java Code - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, properties, property-placeholder

I have properties file in Spring Boot application , with end points mentioned as below :-

```
user.details = /api/{userID}/get-user
```

I am using POJO with `@PropertySource`, `@Configuration` to read values.

Now my requirement is to replace the `userID` value dynamically from the java code after reading it from properties file, when I receive the ID from front end application. I will not pass this value from command line as it does not serve my use case.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue, I am using the environment to get a property that contrais a place holder as example: app.signuplink=confirm?token=${token} But the env.getProperty("app.signuplink") returns an exception, that the placeholder was not resolved...